# Error in Quick Launch

Tags: 2010, error, quick-launch

Today my SharePoint started displaying in the Quick Launch only Error link, all my other links are gone.

When I hover over the error the message displayed is:

```
An error occured while rendering navigation for requested URL: / ******. 
Exception message: unable to cast object of type '<Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedListItem' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.CachedPage'.
Stack trace: at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalWebSiteMapNode.FetchDynamicItems(PublishingWebpubWeb, NodeTypes includeTypes, Boolean&websFetched, Boolean& 
pagesFetched) at Microsoft.Share.Point.Publishing.Navigation.PortalWebSiteMapNode.Populate.Navigation.
```

What happened, any solution?

Comment: Any other ideas regarding restarting the SharePoint Server Publidhing??

Answer (score 1):

You should try with,

1. disable and re-enable Publishing feature and Navigation feature for all sites
2. IIS Reset
3. Unchecked following options in the site collection output cache settings:

   - Enable ouput cache.
   - Publishing sites can use a different page output cache profile.
   - Page layouts can use a different page output cache profile.

[Source](https://praveenix.wordpress.com/2014/03/16/sharepoint-2013-left-navigation-and-top-navigation-bar-does-not-render-links-and-shows-error-an-error-occurred-while-rendering-navigation-for-requested-url/)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. The options from point 3 are unchecked

Comment: Ohk. did you tried by disable and re-enable Publishing feature at site collection level and web level and followed by iis reset?

Comment: When clicking on Navigation at site level collection I get an error "An unexpected error has occurred". How do I reset IIS?

Comment: open your command prompt by pressing keys "Window + R" and type "iisreset" press enter. it will reset your iis.

Comment: I am not an administrator of the site collection. I only have full control. The IIS reset command it's not recognized.

Comment: At one point I selected "Inherit permissions from this parent" in Manage Content and Structure . The menu appeared but after refresh the Error message reappeared.

Comment: I deactivated SharePoint Server Publishing at site collection level. and the menu in quick lunch works. Unfortunetly I cant reactivate SharePoint Server Publishing.

Comment: It gives me the next error: "The feature failed to activate because a list at 'Pages' already exists in this site.  Delete or rename the list and try activating the feature again."

Comment: go to your site content and rename your "Pages" library to "Pages 1" or something and try again to active it.

Comment: renamed... still the same error and same message appears when reactivating SharePoint Server Publishing

Comment: try to rename "Images" & "Documents" libraries also to different name. because SharePoint Server Publishing will create this libraries.

Comment: reamed Images, Documents and Pages... still not working